# IF THEN STATEMENT ORACLE APEX PS/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am trying to calculate taxes, however, I keep getting an error ORA-06550. Can you please aid me?

How it should to work is

- if gross pay is more than 225000 then we divide the gross pay by 3.
- if gross pay is less than 225000 then set the value at 75000

This is what I tried so far:

```
IF nvl(:P37_GROSS_PAY,0) > (225000*nvl:(P37_PERIOD,0)) THEN
   {nvl(:P37_GROSS_PAY,0)/3}

ELSE
   {75000*nvl(:P37_PERIOD,0)}

END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the result into *something*, such as a locally declared variable (and remove curly brackets; they are invalid in this context):

```
declare
  tax number;
begin
  if nvl(:P37_GROSS_PAY, 0) > 22500 * nvl(:P37_PERIOD, 0)) then
     tax := nvl(:P37_GROSS_PAY, 0) / 3;
  else
     tax := 75000 * nvl(:P37_PERIOD, 0);
  end if;
end;
```